# SL5 UserControl is ignoring Application resources

Tags: silverlight, prism, silverlight-5.0

I have a Prism application, with a Main application that contains shell and infrastructure, and a Test module. I removed App.xaml from Test module because I didn't need it (Prism doesn't load it). Now I want to have it back to pust some designtime resources into it. I added App.xaml back manually, set it as a startup object of the project. The App.xaml contains a resource dictionary Style.xml (the same as main application, I linked it) but the UserControl doesn't have them avaliable. Is there anything else that I must revert so the project uses App.xaml? The same resources work if I put them in UserControl.Resources so it's not a mispelling problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to change Build Action of App.xaml to ApplicationDefinition